# Setting a Property value to another property value in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am new to XAML, I want to change the `background` of a button to the color of the `BorderBrush` when I hover above it

Here's the code:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        CornerRadius="15">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" 
                    Value="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

The value of the Cursor changes as it should, the Background however doesn't.

I also tried `RelativeSource={RelativeSource {x:Type BUtton}}` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`RelativeSource.Self`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.relativesource.self?view=windowsdesktop-7.0):

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" 
            Value="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
</Trigger>
```

Be aware however that the Background Setter in the Style Trigger would be ignored  if your directly assign the Button's Background like e.g.

```
<Button Background="Transparent" .../>
```

In that case move the Trigger to the ControlTemplate, with `RelativeSource.TemplatedParent`:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border x:Name="border"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        CornerRadius="15">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="border"
                                Property="Background" 
                                Value="{Binding BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="border"
                                Property="Cursor"
                                Value="Hand"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I tried this before but it doesn't work

Comment: This does of course work. You must have made something else wrong. Maybe you are assigning the value of the Background property directly when you create a Button. Such an assignment would have higher precedence than a Style Setter.

Comment: I made a button with a transparent background and a red border brush, the fill should be red but it isn't, you think something is overriding the style?

Comment: Did you write something like `<Button Background="Transparent" .../>`?

Comment: Yes, and also a border Brush

Comment: Be aware that you need an additional element in the ControlTemplate that visualizes the Button's pressed state.

Comment: Thank you man I was really stuck. I want to ask, why do I have to name the border?

Comment: For `TargetName="border"` in the Setter. Without that, the Setter would target the Button, which does not work for the same reason as the Style Trigger won't work.